# The type or namespace name 'MapInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: dll, mapinfo, mapxtreme

I add mapinfo dll's my project but when i want to add namespace i take error.I add MapInfo.CoreEngine,MapInfo.CoreEngine.Wrapper,MapInfo.CoreTypes and MapInfo.WebControls.I search my dlls path thats correct.

I use MapExtreme 7.3

Comment: when i add MapExtreme 7.2 dlls and configure my web.cofig file for 7.2 i haven't got this error.but when i use 7.3 dlls and configure web.config for 7.3 i take this error.Any Idea?

Comment: No, sorry. Please add more details to your question.

Comment: sorry.I haven't got more details about error.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved error.MapXtreme work with .net framework 4.5.2.Install .Net framework 4.5.2 and your project target framework must be 4.5.2.